# Trigger on Oracle Sql database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have some issues to resolve on my sql database:

- ensure that a player can only have 2 yellow cards or one red
- a team can not have more than 5 foreign players (player who nationality is differet from French)

My model is something like that:

```
Team
-------
team_id (PK)
name

Player
-------
player_id (PK)
team_id (FK)
name
number_yellow_cards
number_red_cards
nationality
```

I think that trigger can resolve my problems. Here is my trigger, but doesn't work in any situation (insert/update)

```
create or replace TRIGGER foreign_players
Before Insert OR UPDATE on Player
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE nr_foreign_players INTEGER;
Begin

  IF INSERTING THEN
    SELECT Count(*) INTO nr_foreign_players
    FROM
        Team T
        INNER JOIN Player P ON P.team_id = T.team_id
    WHERE 
        P.team_id =  :new.team_id 
        AND P.nationality <> 'French';

    if(nr_foreign_players > 5) then
        Raise_Application_Error(-20000,'Error insert' ); 
    End If;
  END IF; --INSERTING

  IF UPDATING THEN
    SELECT Count(*) INTO nr_foreign_players
    FROM
        Team T
        INNER JOIN Player P ON P.team_id = T.team_id
    WHERE 
        P.team_id =  :new.team_id 
        AND P.nationality <> 'French';

    if(nr_foreign_players > 5) then
    Raise_Application_Error(-20000,'Error update' ); 
    End If;
  END IF; --UPDATING


End;
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: "It does not work" is not a question.  What are the specific issues?

Comment: The check for the number of cards could also be implemented in a check constraint.

Comment: Thank you for solution. It will be better if I use constraint option for number of cards. But the count of foreign player, am I really need use trigger right?

Answer (score 0):

This can't a 100% sure answer, as you did not exactly tell us what *doesn't work in any situation*.

I see several issues with your trigger :

1. The logic to ensure that a team can not have more than 5 non-French players seems correct, however why do you duplicate it for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` ? This can be simplified.
2. You are not at all verifying that *a player can only have 2 yellow cards or one red*

Here is an updated SQL code that should get the work done. It is performing each check one by one, raising application exception as soon as one check fails. No distinction is made between `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations, as the logic is exactly the same for both operations.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER foreign_players
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Player
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
    nr_foreign_players INTEGER;
BEGIN

    IF NVL(:new.number_yellow_cards, 0) > 2 THEN
        Raise_Application_Error(-20000, 'Too many yellow cards' ); 
    END IF;

    IF NVL(:new.number_red_cards, 0) > 1 THEN
        Raise_Application_Error(-20000, 'Too many red cards' ); 
    END IF;

    SELECT Count(*) INTO nr_foreign_players
    FROM
        Team T
        INNER JOIN Player P ON P.team_id = T.team_id
    WHERE 
        P.team_id =  :new.team_id 
        AND P.nationality <> 'French';
    IF nr_foreign_players > 5 THEN
        Raise_Application_Error(-20000, 'Too many foreign players' ); 
    END IF;

END;
```

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your response. When I do an update, I receive the error "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation".

My update was: Update Player set number_yellow_cards = 5 where player_id = 5

Comment: Hello @Jcbo, can you please tell me what the trigger compilation error is ? `select * from SYS.USER_ERRORS where NAME = 'foreign_player' and type = 'TRIGGER'`

Comment: I don't have any error when the trigger is compiled. If I do an insert the trigger works, but doesn't work with updates.

Comment: @Jcbo : I did a smal change in the trigger code. Pls let me know what happens now when you do run an `UPDATE`. If it is not working, let me know what the `UPDATE` statement was and which error message you received